# Зелёные пиксели в юнити. Но на самой картинке этого нет

Tags: unity3d

Друзья, Делаю 2д пиксельную игру на юнити, и вот проблема, в фотошопе и вообще в любом редакторе если приблизить у этой картинке нету зелёных пикселей там где земля, в центре вообщем. А в юнити есть, фильтр мод стоит point no filter, по факту проблема именно с этой платформой и еще у персонажа лишнии пиксели в спрайт editor появляются, подскажи как исправить? пробовал разные настройки в sprite renderer но эффекта не было

[image: Вот пример]

Comment: я конечно не супер зрячий, но в центре явно есть зеленые пиксели

Comment: Сверху сама картинка?

Comment: В настройках спрайта компрессию поменяй, для пиксельарта тупо выключи (для редактора и устройства настройки разные)